# Write excel sheets to specific text place (python)

Tags: python, excel

So my goal is instead of writing this script over and over again, I want to iterate it with a for loop into a text file. 
In the text file specific cell i.e. - 'name' will move to the "" after the name parameter.

In my mind I have %s in my head but I can't seem to figure out how to break down the Excel file to suit this text writing.

Here's the text and the excel sheet.

[Arrows representing where I want the text to go from the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf4dI.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a row of the df. For example:

```
df.loc[len(df)]=[text.get("name"), text.get("country"), text.get("address")]
```

Should result in adding another row at the end of the dataframe.